# Why can't Selenium Web Driver find the elements in this case?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Selenium newbie here. The examples I tried so far worked well but now I stumbled upon a case that seemingly doesn't work:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class GeckoDriverTest
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D://XXX/seleniumdrivers/geckodriver.exe");
    FirefoxDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.aerzen.com/de/karriere/stellenangebote.html");

    
    System.out.println("URL = "+driver.getCurrentUrl());
    
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.consent-banner--accept.button.submit")).click();

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    
    System.out.println("URL = "+driver.getCurrentUrl());
    
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr > td > a"));
    System.out.println("Elements: "+elements.size());
    for(WebElement element : elements)
    {
        String url = element.getAttribute("href");
        System.out.println(url);
    }
}
}
```

The first part does work but the "tr > td > a" selector doesn't find any elements although I'm pretty sure they exist (I can see them in the browser window).

Any idea what's going wrong there? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I see 24 elements matching `tr > td > a` there but none of them visible. What elements are you trying to locate here?

Comment: So it's because they are not visible? How can I make them visible?

Comment: You can not and should not. Selenium imitates human GUI actions.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: I try to get the href parameters of the links (the page contains job offers and I want to get the links to the individual offers)

Comment: But where from    ?

Comment: Sorry I don't get your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is inside an iframe. In order to access these elements you will need to switch to that iframe.
Also instead of `tr > td > a` cssSelector try using `table td.real_table_col1 a` cssSelector.
This should work better:

```java
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//iframe")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe")));
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table td.real_table_col1 a"));
    System.out.println("Elements: "+elements.size());
    for(WebElement element : elements)
    {
        String url = element.getAttribute("href");
        System.out.println(url);
    }
```

Also instead of hardcoded pauses like

```java
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

You should use `ExpectedConditions` something like

```java
WebdriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a.consent-banner--accept.button.submit")));
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Even if I use an "a" selector it does find some elements but not the ones I am interested in.

Comment: I have asked you: what are you trying to do here? What hrefs are you looking for?

Comment: I have finetuned the locator to remove the first irrelevant element

Comment: I want the hrefs of the A elements located in the table (therefore, matching "tr > td > a").

Comment: Have you tried your code? Does it work? It doesn't for me, still no matching elements found.

Comment: I see, moment please

Comment: It's an iframe there!

Comment: Ah you're right! Good point!

Comment: If I iterate through the frames (driver.fidneElements(By.tagName("iframe")) I can find the elements I was looking for. So the IFrame was the issue here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Right, the issue was with the iframe. I'll upvote you back later, reached the limit for today 